# Why can i not upgrade my Google Firebase plan from spark to blaze?

Tags: firebase, firebase-console

I'm using firebase for my webapp project and need to upgrade from the free spark plan to blaze to be able to also use firebase cloud functions. Wherever i try to click "upgrade plan" button i get the same empty dialog not showing me any upgrade options as it should.

I already contacted firebase support here https://firebase.google.com/support/troubleshooter/contact

Maybe someone experienced the same problem and has a solution already?

Story short:
The dialog to upgrade my plan ist just empty. I tried different browsers and restarted chrome. I also created another new project where the dialog shows upgrading options to blaze. So it seems like it has something to do with my particular project. So far i used the Firebase Hosting and Firestore.

[screenshot empty plans dialog](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HA3GR.jpg)

Comment: That looks unusual indeed. The steps I'd recommend is 1) to disable any browser extension you may have and try again, 2) run in an incognito window, 3) try in a different browser, 4) try on a different network. If none of these help, [reach out to Firebase support](https://firebase.google.com/support/contact/troubleshooting/) for personalized help in troubleshooting

Comment: thanks for your suggestions! i already tried all of your steps and also tried to do it with another firebase project wich worked totally fine. So i also guess it has to do with my particular project. I'll update the solution here as soon as firebase support helps me out.

Comment: Got awnser from firebase support:
"this issue is usually caused when your project's associated Analytics property has been put in the trash"

1. Restore your trashed Google Analytics property associated with your Firebase project.
2. Link the Firebase project to another Analytics property (can be done through Settings -> Integrations -> Analytics, 3 dots settings icon, unlink Analytics from this project, then in Integrations link through the Analytics card again to a different property).
3. Unlink the Firebase project from Analytics (same as 2, but don't relink after unlinking).

Comment: Phew, that sounds like a tricky restore Philip. Glad to hear support recognized it. Were you able to get things working again?

Comment: yes after restoring that Analytics property i was able to upgrade my plan. Thanks for helping!